# How to create dynamic layouts with STATIC HTML using utility first approach (eg. bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a project where I need to list some products on a web page.  Every few weeks, the page will be sponsored by a different business.  Each business sponsor will request a completely different look and feel.  I wish to write the HTML once, but have separate CSS files for each business that sponsors the page.  As an example, run this code below and click on the screen several times to jump through a few possible layouts:

```js
let count = 0;
const sponsors = ["sponsor1","sponsor2","sponsor3"];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',_=>{
  const item = document.querySelector('.item');
  for(let c=0;c<5;c++)
    document.querySelector('.articles').innerHTML += item.outerHTML;

  document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item=>item.addEventListener('click',_=>document.querySelector('body').className=sponsors[(++count)%sponsors.length]));
});
```

```css
body,div,h2,p {padding:0;margin:0;}

/* Sponsor 1 */
.sponsor1 .articles {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.sponsor1 .item {
  display:block;
  background:#333;
  color:white;

  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:10px;
  width:33.333%;
  height:30vh;
  border:2px solid white;
}

.sponsor1 .item:nth-child(1) {
  width:100%;
  height:75vh;
}
.sponsor1 .item:nth-child(8n+2),
.sponsor1 .item:nth-child(8n+3) {
  width: 50%;
  height:50vh;
}

/* Sponsor 2 */
.sponsor2 .articles {
  width:800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.sponsor2 .item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  background:#333;
}
.sponsor2 h2,
.sponsor2 p {
  position:relative;
  left: 100%; 
  padding:20px;
}

.sponsor2 .item:nth-child(even) {
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
}

.sponsor2 .item:nth-child(even) h2,
.sponsor2 .item:nth-child(even) p {
  position:relative;
  left: -100%; 
}

/* Sponsor 3 */
.sponsor3 .articles {
  width:1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position:relative;
}
.sponsor3 .item {
  background:#ccc;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:absolute;
}
.sponsor3 .item:first-child {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background:#666;
  color:white;
  padding:50px;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(n+2) {
  overflow:visible;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(n+2) h2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  padding-left:1rem;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(n+2) p {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:2rem;
  padding-left:1rem;
  width:600px;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(2) {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  top:60vh;
  left:150px;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(3) {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  top:80vh;
  left:700px;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(4) {
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  top:95vh;
  left:40px;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(5) {
  width:250px;
  height:300px;
  top:130vh;
  left:800px;
}
.sponsor3 .item:nth-child(6) {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  top:150vh;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsor1">
  <div class="articles">
      <div class="item">
        <h2>Project</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Widget above doesn't seem to render properly so use this link to view code in action:** https://johnlai2004.github.io/layout/

I wish to learn how to develop with a utility-first css approach.  As such, I wish to learn how to use bootstrap.  My challenge is that I can't think of a way to structure my HTML or classes like `container`, `row`, `col-*` in a way that supports all the possible layout configurations I need.  Whatever configuration I ascribe for one layout, the extra `div` tags or the extra `classes` conflicts with my attempts to create another layout.  I am keen on not modifying my HTML code once it has been published.  And any new visual presentations that are requested by business sponsors should be achieved strictly through CSS files.

Is there a way in bootstrap (or any other css framework) to:

1. Ascribe all these utility classes to an scss file in the form of mixins or variables?
2. Avoid using `container` and `row` wrappers to do layout?

Comment: why repeating the same question with different words? edit the old one instead

Comment: The last one is different because the "number of items" will change.  It deals with re-rendering HTML as a result of search. In this one, the number of items is fixed, the html is static, but the visual presentation must change, and there will be no user events.